# Why does printf() print ffffff before actual data. C

Tags: c, printf

printf() function prints leading ffffff (technically I understand that most significant bit carries sign so it gets carried all the way to where data starts). But how to get rid of them I have no idea and why is it happening?

```
int mem_display(Cmd *cp, char *arguments)
{
  int i;
  char *adr;
  if (!sscanf(arguments,"%x",&adr))
  {
      return 0;
  }
  printf("%#0.8s ",arguments);

  for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    printf("%02.x ",(unsigned int)*(adr+i));
  }
...
```

the output:

```
 % UNIX> md 10668 
/*calling function show memory location 0x10668*/
    OUT:
     10668 ffffffbc 10 20 ffffffe0 ffffffa0 40 ffffffa2 ffffffa0 44 ffffff9c 23 ffffffa0 20
```

solved:

```
printf("%0.2x ",(unsigned int)*(adr+i));
```

output:

```
UNIX> md 10000
 10000 7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 .ELF............
```

Comment: Why are you using a `.` and `(unsigned int)` is very likely wrong.

Comment: You shall not dereference an address you just entered, that is _undefined behaviour_ (unless it is the same value you just printed from the same program execution). Also the format-specifier is wrong for a pointer and the type has to be `void *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast to `unsigned char` to have the system consider `*(adr+i)` as unsigned, so that no sign expansion will be done.

```
for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
    printf("%02.x ",(unsigned char)*(adr+i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [`printf()` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), this is the correct way

```
printf("%02x ", (unsigned char) adr[i]);
```

---

<sub>**Note**: don't use this `*(a + i)` notation, and specially when you are casting it. It's not a bad way to dereference a pointer, it's just not appropriate in this particular situation.</sub>